# Can anyone tell me how these condensed typefaces are created?

Tags: fonts

I have seen the following before in different math publications. Could anyone explain how the words 'GMRES, CG, BICGSTAB' are being created to give them that condensed typeface?

[image]

Comment: `\textsc{GMRES}`

Comment: @Herbert you mean `\textsc{gmres}`!

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! These are "small capitals" font.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This typeface is called small caps, and is produced with the `\textsc` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Krylov Subspace Methods (KSMs), such as \textsc{gmres},
\textsc{cg},\textsc{bicgstab} and numerous...
\end{document}
```

[image: rendering]

Comment: In many typefaces, "small caps" are actually "petite caps." The OP's example seems to be true small caps, which are noticeably taller than lowercase letters. Petite caps are about the same size as lowercase.